# How to use Laravel Blade in JS (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I am developing a blog project in Laravel 5.6. I am using the Laravel built-in function called `str_slug()` to convert titles into slugs and JavaScript to auto generate the slugs using JavaScript's `keyup` function. Here's my code:

```
var postTitle = $('#post-title');
var postSlug = $('#post-slug');
postTitle.keyup(function() {
    postSlug.val({{ str_slug(postTitle.val()) }});
});
```

However, it's throwing an error of unknown constant. Can anyone tell me how to what I want? I am new to Laravel.

Comment: That will never work, `str_slug` is a PHP function which is evaluated on the server before ever being sent to the client. Making an Ajax request or using a javascript slug generator are you two best bets.

Comment: can u refer me to a JS helper function which can convert a title in a slug

Comment: Here you go: https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify

Comment: Thanks bro for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple function to create a slug in JS:

```
function slugify(text)
{
  return text.toString().toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
    .replace(/^-+/, '')             // Trim - from start of text
    .replace(/-+$/, '');            // Trim - from end of text
}
```

[Source Gist](https://gist.github.com/mathewbyrne/1280286)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the html markup to get this done. In the html mark up create a hidden input and put in the value of `str_str()` operation on the post-title and in your js set the post-slug input value to that on keyup.

```
<input type="text" id="post-title" value="{{$title}}">
<input type="hidden" id="hidden-post-title" value="{{str_slug($title)}}">

var postTitle = $('#post-title');
var postSlug = $('#post-slug');
postTitle.keyup(function() {
    postSlug.val($('#hidden-post-title').val());
});
```